# c++ - GetAsyncKeyState makes my program crash when I open it

Tags: c++, crash

So I'm making a game that runs on the console. I started with some functions to make drawing to the screen easier, and that worked fine. Then when I tried to add input (using the function GetAsyncKeyState), the program crashed as soon as I started the program. It said: "Text Game.exe has stopped working" Here's how I handled the code:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState('A' && 0x8000)) {
    x -= 1;
}
if(GetAsyncKeyState('D' && 0x8000)) {
    x += 1;
}
if(GetAsyncKeyState('W' && 0x8000)) {
    y += 1;
}
if(GetAsyncKeyState('S' && 0x8000)) {
    y += 1;
}
```

If it helps, I got this method by reading this:
[How to check if a Key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600981/how-to-check-if-a-key-is-pressed)

EDIT: So I ran it in debug mode, and it said it crashed when I ran a function I made called "refreshScreen();". I don't know why though. Here's the code:

```
void refreshScreen() {
    system("CLS");
    for ( int i = 0; i < screenHeight; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < screenWidth; j++ ) {
            cout << screen[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It's meant to clear the console, then print all of the contents of array "screen". "Screen", by the way, is the buffer that I write to.

Comment: Have you debugged it to get the stack trace?

Comment: Also, should the `W` action be `y -= 1`?

Comment: Your code is wrong, but I doubt this is the cause of your crash. If it is, then there likely is something else wrong with your program that is acting in conjunction with this.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I do have to make y smaller when I press the 'W' key, because in my program, (0,0) is in the top-right corner.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I did add the game loop recently, but I got the same result without that, just running the code normally. Also I fixed the logical "and" into a bitwise "and" (I assume that was the problem) but got the same result.

Comment: @Nathonion You have `y += 1` for both W and S.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use the `GetAsyncKeyState` as it's described in answers by the link you provided, you are doing it wrong.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) says the following:

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

So what is done in the answer by the link you provided:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 0x8000)
{ /*key is down*/ }
```

In the if statement there bitwise "and" operation is performed on return value of `GetAsyncKeyState` function and `0x8000` constant - which equals to `0x8000` the most significant bit is set or equals to `0` when it is not set.

What is your code doing:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState('A' && 0x8000)) // ...
```

logical "and" operation between `'A'` and `0x8000` constant - gives `true` which is casted to `1` and passed to `GetAsyncKeyState` as an argument.

[EDIT]: As it was mentioned in comments, `1` [corresponds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) to left mouse button. So all `if` conditions will be `true` in case left mouse button is down and will be `false` otherwise. Probably, crash appears in different part of your program after unexpected change of `x` and `y` values. You should debug your program to localize the crash.

Comment: All true, though there is no reason the code should crash because of this. 1 is a valid VK code, it's the left mouse button. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, `GetAsyncKeyState` function should not crash. Most probably, crash appears after this code snippet because of unexpected `x` and `y` variable values.

Comment: @k.v. The x and y variables can't be unexpected because one: I use Code::Blocks, and when it compiles, it usually tells me when a variable hasn't been initialized, and two: I did initialize them earlier in the code.

Comment: by unexpected I mean that all your `if`s will trigger together.

Comment: So maybe if I used a switch statement? Or a string of if elses?