# I need ASCII key code for Shift key. All the numbers I've found on the internet doesn't work

Tags: c++

I'm using C++, getch() function. I've done some research and they said that it's 14, 15 or 16, 17. But none work. Key code for up and down arrow (72 and 80) work fine though.

Comment: There is no "ASCII key code" for the shift key. ASCII consists of discrete letters, numbers, and punctuation. Neither is there an "ASCII key code" for any "arrows". I'm sure there's a wikipedia chart of ASCII codes, and you won't find any arrows there. So, whatever you're looking at, it's not ASCII codes, so your question is unclear.

Comment: I think you'll have to go beyond getch(), like they say here ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/41600981/5590742 ), there is no cross platform way to do it. What platform are you writing for?  This search may help you: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+detect+shift+key

Comment: `getch()` doesn't respond to the Shift keys (only to other keys pressed at the same time they are held down). What on earth are you actually trying to achieve? If you want the scan-codes, then you're down at the operating system level - which, given the nature of your question, is extremely unlikely. If you add what you're trying to achieve (not how you think you need to do it) to your question, you'll receive a helpful answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

ASFAIK there is no ASCII code for the `shift` key. You can refer to the ASCII table found [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

I think what you are being confused about is that in the ASCII table there are values of: `14` and `15` or `E` & `F` in hex. These have the properties of `shift in` and `shift out` which were used many years ago which are rarely used any more and many of the first set of numbers aren't even used for their original purposes.

However, in `<WinUser.h>` header file; there is a bunch of defines for many different keys and where the `Shift Key` is concerned it is defined as such:

```
#define VK_SHIFT 0x10
```

However; if you are writing a function to handle keyboard input through key presses and releases using a Window's `messageHandler()` function to get Windows Messages; you can not use `VK_SHIFT` directly because you have to do bit manipulation to test if it is the `Left Shift` or the `Right Shift`. This is determined by the bits that were set.

Here is what a possible if statement would look like when querying for the shift key...

```
if ( (wParam == VK_SHIFT) && ((lParam & 0x360000) == 0x360000) ) {
    wParam = VK_RSHIFT;
}
```

Other than that; I do not know exactly what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score -1):

```
// you can implement the shift key in your custom keyboard by doing like this
 
   <Row>
    <Key android:keyWidth="14.275%p" android:horizontalGap="1%p" 
     android:codes="-1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:isModifier="true" 
     android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_shift_normal"/>
 
    <Key android:keyWidth="14.275%p"
   android:codes="-5"
   android:keyEdgeFlags="right" 
   android:isModifier="true"
   android:isRepeatable="true" 
   android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_backspace"/>
  </Row>
```